# Conditional formatting with Libreoffice Calc activated with a letter and the condition being applied to more than one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

Is there a way to do condition formatting based on a letter and having that format apply to more than one cell?
The desired result is shown below, where typing either A, B, or C in column "B" for a certain row would result in both columns "A" and "B" of that row changing colors from green, yellow, and red respectively.

[image: Illustration of desired result]

I've tried the conditional formatting options to make the color change based on characters (In Libreoffice Calc, through "Format -> Conditional -> "Color Scale"), but without success.

[image: Illustration of what was attempted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select B1 and create 3 conditions: one for each color. Use the `Formula is` condition and set it as `$B1="A"`. Set the range to `A1:B1`. Create conditions for B2 and B3 and change the formula to `B` and `C` respectively.
2. Follow the same process as in step 1, but select B2 and change the formula and the range to `$B2="A"` and set the range to `A2:B2`. Create also conditions for `B` and `C`.
3. The same process applies as on step 1 and 2. The formula however changes to `$B3="A"`, the range to to `A3:B3`.

You will have 3 conditional formats. Each conditional format will have 3 conditions. See images below.

**Conditions**

*(note: replace `$B$1`, `$B$2`, and `$B$3` with `$B1`, `$B2`, and `$B3` respectively)*

[image: IMG:]

**Conditional formats**

[image: IMG:]

**Result**

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thanks @Reddy. While this did technically work, is there a way to make those conditions copy-and-paste-able, where I do the three conditions for one row, and then simply just copy and paste the cell for it to apply to another row? It would be very time consuming to have to do this for every row when hundreds to thousands of rows are expected.

Comment: I got it, based on a "reverse engineering" of steps shown in this page (https://trumpexcel.com/highlight-rows-based-on-cell-value/), it turns out your steps work when instead of typing $B$1="A", type $B1="A". Afterwards, I just need to make those three conditions once, and then can simply copy and paste the row to repeat the same conditional formatting for another row.

Comment: @plu Yes, that how to do it.